# How to get link value inside href

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a div tag in which a tag is enclosed.
How can i get the value `href`?

For example, "https://www.tweeter.com/rkShukl" from `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="https://www.tweeter.com/rkShukl"></a>
```

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the language bindings. In java it is `getAttribute()`:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id('id_of_the_link'));
element.getAttribute('href');
```

In Python it is `get_attribute()`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('id_of_the_link')
element.get_attribute('href')
```

Answer (score 1):

alecxe is correct just one correction I had to do when using it was instead of

```
element.getAttribute('href');
```

I had to use double quotes for Java. It was assuming it was a character literal.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id('id_of_the_link'));
element.getAttribute("href");
```